# Extract Text from CSS Property using Selenium Python

Tags: python, html, css, selenium

I have an input tag html element that Selenium Python fails to identify (not because of the wait). So on a web page with a form (name is Form1), I want to extract the text in one of the fields. This is the html element here when I inspect the elements on chrome:

Input Element:

```
<input name="txtSerialNo" type="text" readonly="readonly" id="txtSerialNo" class="tbFormRO" style="width:160px;position:absolute;left:90px;top:7px;text-align:center;">
```

The full xpath is this when I right-click on the element to copy the xpath: `/html/body/form/div[9]/input[1]`

#### The HTML Element

[image: The HTML element]

There isn't any text on it, so I tried the below and all did not work. I also tried the implicit wait and WebDriverWait. They are irrelevant and did not work.

```
driver.maximize_window() 
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/form/div[9]/input[1]') 
driver.find_element_by_id('txtSerialNo')
driver.find_element_by_name("txtSerialNo")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='txtSerialNo']")
```

It all returns error:

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="txtSerialNo"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=91.0.4472.114)
```

My question is: I can see that when I inspect the element, the text I want to retrieve is in the Property tab, under input#txtSerialNo.tbFormRO

#### Under Property

[image: Under Property]

I am using a for loop to gather all input element, but I don't know how to extract that "value" property under the "category" of `input#txtSerialNo.tbFormRO` in the property tab when I inspect the element. Sorry I don't have a solid CSS/HTML knowledge.

#### The Text I Want to Extract

[image: This has the text I want to extract: 116A43802-1]

I tried the below without success:

```
for inp in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//form[@name="Form1"]//input'):
    for k in inp.get_property('attributes')[0].keys(): 
        print(inp.get_attribute(k))

for inp in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//form[@name="Form1"]//input'):
    print(inp.value_of_css_property('value'))
    # get_property(input#txtSerialNo.tbFormRO.text)  
    # .get_attribute('text')   
    # .get_attribute("innerHTML")  
    # .get_attribute('value')
    # .get_property('input#txtSerialNo.tbFormRO.value')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `.get_attribute()`.  Based on the image lets adjust the xpath to `'//input[@name="txtSerialNo"]'`

```
for inp in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//input[@name="txtSerialNo"]'):
    print(inp.get_attribute('value'))
```

Comment: thank you for your response! But it doesn't print anything, and the ```driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//input[@name="txtSerial"]')``` returns an empty list

Comment: @doryk Sorry about that it looks like I missed to characters. I updated it to use `txtSerialNo`

Comment: thank you~ but it doesn't change anything, still an empty list and doesn't print anything in the for loop: ```driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//input[@name="txtSerialNo"]')```